# Unable to install and configure the local cli to lower version to build the project

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I  have installed nvm for windows along with two versions of nodes. The node versions installed are 8.12.0 and 7.3.0. I need to have the latest version angular/cli at the global level and old version of the cli at the local level.
The reason I am doing this is because we are in a transition stage, where our old angular projects that is using old cli would be migrated eventually to the most recent version.

I have run the following command to install the latest at the global level

npm install -g @angular/cli@6.2.3 and tried installing the local cli on one my project using the following command npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@1.4.2.

I get the following message after installing 1.4.2

```
`-- @angular/cli@1.4.2
  +-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular-devkit/core@0.0.29
  `-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular-devkit/schematics@0.0.52
```

When i try to execute ng build on my local project folder , get message

```
You are running version v7.3.0 of Node.js, which is not supported by Angular CLI v6.
The official Node.js version that is supported is 8.9 and greater.
```

The current node that I have set is

nvm use 7.3.0. This is the version of node that we have been using for all existing projects

I am under the impression that when you ng build, the angular cli in the local folder kicks in . Not sure why it is not happening in this case.